# How to automate python scripts in AWS to send email notification and sends log file and if it have dependencies

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

I have python scripts

script1.py

script2.py

script3.py

script4.py

from my local machine when I ran those scripts it creates log files so I will send those log files to email manually

first script is creates one log file when i ran and 2nd scripts creates one log file

in 2nd script we have logic which creates JSON file using DBEAVER Database data and upload that JSON file in HUBSPOT API using token and API info

now i want to automate those scripts in AWS, I have python code how can I deploy and automate scripts which needs to send log file and email

second python script is having some logic which connect to Dbeaver Database extract users data and convert in to json and upload that json file in HUBSPOT api

In aws how it crates that json file and how it upload those json file every week

can anyone please help me on this i'm very new to AWS

here is the sample code example

```
    import***

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class LOAD:
    def DB_conn(self):
            self.connection  = psycopg2.connect(
            host= '', database= "!!", user= "@@",password= "**",port = "#",)
        fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
            fh.setFormatter(f)
            logger.addHandler(fh)
    def Data(self):
        try:

            conn = self.DB_conn()
            query= 'select ******'
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            number_rows = f"Total number of rows in table:  {cursor.rowcount}\n"
            logger.info(number_rows)    
        --------------------
        ------------------
           logger.info('converting dict to json data\n')
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            filename = now.strftime('User_data_file_%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S.json')
            with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
                json.dump(json_stri, f,indent = 4,default=str)   
            logger.info('JSON File successfully Created!!!\n')
    except Exception as e:
            print("\n--- ERROR OCCURED ---\n\n",e,"\n\n--- QUITTING TASK ---\n")
            logger.error(f'FAILED TO CREATE JSON\n {e} \n')
        
     def chunk_list(list_to_chunk, number_of_list_items):
             """Yield successive chunk_size-sized chunks from list."""
             for i in range(0, len(list_to_chunk), number_of_list_items):
                 yield list_to_chunk[i:i + number_of_list_items]     
         try:
             url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/batch'
             headers = {
                 'Authorization':  "Bearer p*****-bfa4-",
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
    with open(filename,'r') as run:
                 json_data = json.load(run)
    
     r = requests.post(
                         url,
                         data=json.dumps(json_data),
                         headers=headers,
                         verify=False,
                         timeout=(10, 15),
                         stream=True
                     )
    if r.status_code == '200':
        logger.info("File uploaded successfully")
    except Exception as e:
             logger.error(f'FAILED TO LOAD JSON FIle\n ERROR:> {e} \n')
             logger.error(f'ERROR OCCURED----\n\n ERROR:> {e} \n\n--- QUITTING TASK --- \n')
if __name__=='__main__':
    BATCH=LOAD()
    BATCH.Data()
```

so this is the logic of second script, can anyone please suggest ideas

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if your tasks take no longer than 15 minutes and require 10GBs of memory consider moving those code parts to lambda functions. If your tasks take longer than that you can consider AWS Batch/EC2/ECS where you can handle long running tasks.

For automation part you can take a look at EventBridge. In there you can create synchronous (cron-based) or asynchronous (event-based) triggers to start your workflow.

Finally if you have more than one lambda function and you want to orchestrate them, take a look at Step Functions, which is relatively easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution consists of two parts:**

1. Get the logs (optionally) and JSON files in an S3 Bucket. Create an S3 Bucket and Lambda function based on your code that does the job and sends the JSON into the Bucket. Trigger the Lambda periodically using Event Bridge.
2. Create a SQS Queue and add a S3ObjectCreatedNotification, subscribe a send-email-function to the SQS, here is a good [article](https://aws.plainenglish.io/system-design-s3-events-to-lambda-vs-s3-events-to-sqs-sns-to-lambda-2d41477d1cc9) on that. Finally, send the files from S3 to emails in the send-email-function's logic.

**Recommendation:**

1. Sending all logs to S3 is unnecessary unless specifically required. Each function generates log streams in CloudWatch, where you can configure a Subscription Filter to send email notifications, for example, when an ERROR occurs. This approach is widely used and [recommended](https://medium.com/srcecde/send-notification-based-on-cloudwatch-logs-filter-patterns-41bcf616cd02).
2. Sending the JSON files from your code to an S3 Bucket can be accomplished relatively easily using [AWS-SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_PutObject_section.html)
3. Use SES to send emails.
4. Depending on your requirements, you might consider storing the JSON files in S3, particularly if you are dealing with files that exceed the email size limit. In such a scenario, the approach to the solution will vary.
5. Automate the process by utilizing the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will check your points and i will let you know!